# Provability of ~~P in System LJ

Tags: logic

Does there exist a statement $\vdash P$ which is provable in System LK such that $\vdash \neg\neg P$ is not provable in System LJ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes in full LJ, no in the propositional fragment.

If you can derive a formula $\varphi$ in the propositional fragment of LK, then you can derive its double negation, $\neg\neg \varphi$ in the propositional fragment of LJ. This is known as [Glivenko's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation#Propositional_logic).

Glivenko's theorem fails badly in predicate logic. For example, one clearly cannot derive $\vdash \neg\neg \forall x. P(x) \vee \neg P(x)$ in LJ, even though $\vdash \forall x. P(x) \vee \neg P(x)$ is trivially derivable in LK.

Instead, we have slightly more complicated ways to translate from LJ to LK. The simplest such translation adds a double negation in front of *every subformula* of the given formula. If you do that, you get $\neg\neg \forall x. \neg\neg (\neg\neg P(x) \vee \neg\neg\neg P(x))$, which you can indeed prove in LJ.

There are multiple different ways to be more economical with double-negation than the simple method above, which gives rise to many so-called *double-negation translations*.

For example, the *Gödel–Gentzen translation* adds a double negation in front of every atomic subformula, and every subformula whose main logical symbol is either $\vee$ or $\exists$, but leaves the other subformulas alone. Applied to $\forall x. P(x) \vee \neg P(x)$, it gives $\forall x. \neg\neg (P(x) \vee \neg P(x))$.

The *Kuroda translation* instead adds a double-negation in front of the entire formula, and replaces all its subformulas of the form $\forall x.\psi$ with $\forall x. \neg\neg \psi$. Unlike the other translations discussed above, the Kuroda translation reduces to Glivenko's theorem when applied to a propositional LK formula. However, applied to $\forall x. P(x) \vee \neg P(x)$, it gives $\neg\neg \forall x. \neg\neg (P(x) \vee \neg P(x))$.